# Select order products in MySQL from muliple tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables:

- `orderProducts` (`orderId`, `productId`, `productValue`),
- `products` (`productId`, `productName`)
- `values` (`productId`, `productValue`, `productValuePrice`).

I need to select order products (product id, name, value, price) with defined `orderId`.
How to do that with one MySQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `left join` to return rows in the `orderProducts` table for which no corresponding rows in the other tables exist.  Any missing columns will be NULL, allowing you to flag an error condition.  The default `join` is an `inner join`, and will only return rows with matching entries in both joined tables.

```
select op.product id, p.name, v.productValue, p.productValuePrice
from orderProducts op
left join products p on p.productId = op.productId
left join values v 
    on v.productId = op.productId
    and v.productValue = op.productValue
where op.orderId = <YourOrderId>
```

Comment: You forgot to put another condition in `left join values`, must be `left join values v on (v.productId = op.productId) and (v.productValue = op.productValue)`

Comment: @Semyon: Right, that's hard to see without knowing your data model.  Answer edited

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a join, something like:

```
Select o.orderId, p.productId, p.name, o.productValue, v.productValuePrice
From products p
     Join values v on p.productId = v.productId
     Join orderProducts o on p.productId = o.orderId
Where orderId = 5
```

Comment: he said "with defined orderId.", needs WHERE clause, doesn't it :)

Comment: @Sarfraz  - `Order`'s a keyword in my head as well evidently...  Good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

.......

```
 select p.productId, p.productName, o.productValue, v.prodctValuePrice from orderProducts o  join products p on o.productId = p.productId join values v on v.productId = p.productId where p.productId = 1
```